# How would I develop a relationship User belongs to Groups in Mongoose & Node.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to teach myself node.js, coming from Rails, and I want to establish this relationship:

- A group has_many users, a user belongs_to group

How would I go about doing this in my models?

```
//for user
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var UserSchema = new Schema({
    name: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

//for group
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var GroupSchema = new Schema({
    name: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Group', GroupSchema);
```

Also I would like to allow a moderator to kick someone out of a group if the person were obnoxious. How could I target a user belonging to a group and then delete the user. It seems more complicated than the traditional CRUD methods. Do I need nested resources like in rails, or the equivalent?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Mongoose has a feature called [*population*](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) that you can use to set up "relationships" (MongoDB only has limited support for relationships).

Your schema would look something like this:

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
  name : String,
  group: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Group' }
});

var GroupSchema = new Schema({
  name  : String,
  users : [ { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' } ]
});
```

In other words: the User model has a `group` property which points to the group the user belongs to, and the Group model has a `users` property (an array) that contains references to the users that belong to the group.

To associate a user to a group (assuming that `group` is a variable that is a Group instance):

```
user.group = group;
user.save(...);
```

And to add the user to a group:

```
group.users.push(user);
group.save(...);
```

However, you should be aware that array properties in MongoDB documents have limited scalability. I think that a few dozen items in an array will work just fine, but when the number of users in a group are expected to be in the thousands, this probably won't be a viable solution. In that situation, you probably should consider a "junction collection" (similar to SQL's "junction table").

To remove a user from a particular group, I think you need to use `.update()`:

```
Group.update({ _id: group._id }, { $pull : { users : user._id }})
```